# Windows phone calendar integration

Tags: windows-phone-8, calendar

We are building a simple we app that contains basic tasking functionality (tasks, appointments, etc.).

We want to integrate it with Windows Phone 8 native Calendar, without writing any apps but by making a some sort of webservice that could be added as an account to Windows phone (e.g. Facebook, Microsoft Live, Gmail - are all accounts that are added, thus the tasks are synced).

Yet what have I came up with was this:

[Interacting with calendars (Live Connect API)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/live/hh826523.aspx#top)

This looks like a way to actively push and control the items on the Microsoft Live account, which would be fine but it requires that account to make it happen and an active module to do all the management.

We are looking forward to mimicking account behaviour and letting the phone do all the work :)

CalDAV was another keyword that popped up while searching but to my understanding windows phone doesn't support it.

Is it possible to forcefeed windows phone calendar objects to the phone without making a custom app?

Comment: You can ask the user to subscribe to your calendar using their Outlook.com account. The subscribed calendar will then popup on the users Windows Phone and Windows device as well as at Outlook.com.

Comment: To my understanding that would only partially solve the problem, because I would be limited to calendar events (not tasks) and as noted by Microsoft: "<...>, those changes automatically appear in your calendar within 24-48 hours."

Comment: Maybe try to implement an ActiveSync server?

Answer (score 2):

Windows phone 8.1 supports cardav/caldav. You can put a custom dav server address selecting icloud account (it is a workaround) and editing the dav url. So you can set up a dav server in your app and synch calendars and contacts between your web app and the wp8 defaukt calendars and contacts app.